# TexStudio 2.12.4 (hg 6475:fe21cf14c0b4) Compile not defined

Tags: compiling, texstudio

Selecting 'Compile' from the quickstart menu, the following error occurs:
"Command txs:///compile not defined".

However, choosing 'Tools | Command| LuaLatex from the menus, starts the compile process which runs normally.

Similarly when 'View' is selected the following error occurs: "Command txs:///view not defined".

I have reinstalled TexStudio 12.12.4 with no success.

I installed TexStudio 12.12.2 which runs with no problems, compiling and displaying the same files files in an external pdf reader.

I have tried copying the contents of the build section of preferences in texstudio.ini 12.12.2 to 12.12.4 with no success.

I would appreciate any advice - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by removing the following:

% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

I do not know why this is causing it, other than TeXStudio is not interpreting the code correctly.

I did not experience the problem with View command.

Hope this helps.